# CodeIgniter helper inside controllers

Tags: forms, codeigniter, controller, helper

can i call helper functions inside controller classes?

let's say i have this controller with the _open_form method

```
class User extends Controller {
 function _open_form($action){
  print_r(form_open($action));
 }
}
```

i tried echoing out the result of form_open()
but it returns null. it seems that helper functions can't be called inside controllers

if your wondering why i need to use it inside the controller instead in the view
because we are required to use the given template parser xD

Comment: Just as an FYI, you should not be generating view code in the Controller. Put this form_open in your view file.

Comment: im using smarty xD that's why im putting it on the controller then pass it to $data['form_open'] then echo it out {$form_open} in smarty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lolololol

i figured it out. it seems that the view file did not escaped the result of form_open()

try using htmlentities(form_open($action));

it should escape < and > symbols

lol sorry for the stupid question :))

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the helper file?

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need to load it inside your function:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

More details here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html